# JQuery Async postback issue, how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following JQuery code which does similar functionality like Stackoverflow where the user clicks on the comment link and it displays the comments or in this case replies to a member's status update, generally it works great except when a member posts a new status update which updates the list of status updates using an ajax async postback in ASP.net MVC.

What happens is if you click on the new item in the list it brings them to a new page instead of doing what the JQuery is suppose to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $("a[id ^='commentLink-']").click(function() {
            match = this.id.match(/commentLink-(\d+)/);
            container = $("div#commentContainer-" + match[1])
            container.toggle();

            if (container.is(":visible")) {
                container.load($(this).attr("href"));
            } else {
                container.html("Loading...");
            }
            return false; //Prevent default action
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** I think what is causing it is the fact that the new item in the list isn't actually on the page as the list was updated through the ajax so the new html isn't there until the page is refreshed.

**Update** Okay how would I use this live/event functionality that Paolo Bergantino spoke of in his answer to trigger an ASP.net MVC ActionResult?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the new [`Events/live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) feature in jQuery 1.3

> Binds a handler to an event (like click) for all current - and future - matched element.

So as you add new items, jQuery should add the click event to them with this.

If for some odd reason you do not want to upgrade to jQuery 1.3, you can check out the [`livequery`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery/livequery) plugin.

**EDIT in response to update**:

The actual code to use `.live` would be something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("a[id ^='commentLink-']").live('click', function(event) {
        match = this.id.match(/commentLink-(\d+)/);
        container = $("div#commentContainer-" + match[1])
        container.toggle();

        if (container.is(":visible")) {
            container.load($(this).attr("href"));
        } else {
            container.html("Loading...");
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The changes that were made are mostly in the 2nd line, where

```
$("a[id ^='commentLink-']").click(function() {
```

was replaced by

```
$("a[id ^='commentLink-']").live('click', function(event) {
```

I am now also receiving the argument `event` to use for `event.preventDefault();` which is the way you are recommended to stop events by jQuery. If `return false;` does the trick, though, you can keep that.

I haven't used `.live` yet, but I think that should do the trick. Make sure that you get jQuery 1.3 in your server before trying this, though. :)

Comment: Yeah this looks good but what the problem is, is the DOM elements aren't actually there...so that is what is confusing the Jquery

Comment: What do you mean the elements aren't actually there? I thought the problem was that when a user put in a new status update and it got added to the page, the click handler wasn't working and it was just behaving as a regular link?

Comment: Right but the list is update via an ASP.net MVC ajax actionresult and thus if you view the source of the page those new updates are physically there yet unless you hit F5 to refresh the page...

Comment: If the elements are being updated dynamically they won't show in the source (unless you use 'View Generated Source' in Firefox using the Web Developer plugin) but if you are physically seeing them in the page this is what you need. Otherwise I'm confused.

Comment: No you're right... I'm the one confused... Answer me this then how exactly would I use this live event thingy to trigger a MVC ActionResult?

Comment: Thanks, is there specific syntax though to call the actionResult from the triggered event?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a ASP.NET guy, I'm not sure what you mean... If you already have the AJAX code working where users can add a status update, this code will simply attach events to the new links that are added through that.

Comment: Cool actually I just gavei t a whorl and it worked... thank you very much for your help